# CRC, parity bit, checksum

Tags: checksum, detect, crc, parity

Given 2 bytes of data, let say I've 2 bit error.
**Which one will be the best to use to detect the error?**

1D parity bit where one bit is computed for every byte in the data,

or

8 bit checksum computed from every byte in the data,

or

CRC 8 scheme with generator 100000001

Answer (score 1):

An 8-CRC is guaranteed to detect the error.  A checksum is not -- the error in the two bits might cancel in the sum.  A one-bit parity check is guaranteed to *not* detect a two-bit error.